# Font in CSS Stylesheet not being rendered

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

Just looking to see if anyone has encountered similar issue..

So i deployed a .net core blazor web app, to the server. And its rendering perfectly on everyone's screen's as it should.. But oddly (For my manager).. All the stylesheets are being applied, but the custom font is not being applied.. He has tried to re-install chrome, edge etc.. With no luck..

Oddly it works for everyone else.. Anyone had the same issue? Is their a way to pass in the font any other way?

Or anything else i can try, to get this working?

Thanks in advance.

I have this stylesheet -

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Sausage Sans Black';
    src: url('');
    src: url('file:///C:\SausageFonts\SausageSans_Prof_Black.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Sausage Sans Roman';
    src: url('');
    src: url('file:///C:\SausageFonts\SausageSans_Prof_Roman.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
}
```

And then i have a Fonts folder in my app with the same name - Do i need to put the url's as relative paths? or keep the font files in the url its asking?

On further reading, i can see that you can put the font on a server and then request it.. How would you do this and then call it?

Comment: Font-family usually have back-up fonts if the font is not found. As @Austin said, check the if the font is installed.

Comment: Sorry, guys, how do i check this? and where would it be stored. And where to install if he hasn't?